# Unable to mount exit code 12

Tags: mount

I'm trying to recover data from an internal HDD with no OS running Ubuntu 12.04 from an usb drive. With fdisk-l I get this:

```
   Device  Boot    Start        End      Blocks  ID  System
/dev/sda1             63  976771119  488385528+  42  SFS
```

I don't know what to do, thanks for helping this poor noob

Comment: Any reason you're using SFS File System?

Comment: no, as long as I remember it was NTFS i don't even know what SFS is

Answer (score 1):

Try this to fix:

You need to use the ntfsfix command, which is part of NTFS-3g. NTFS-3g should be installed by default.  If for some reason its not, then just press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>T</kbd> on your keyboard to open Terminal. When it opens, run the command below:

```
sudo apt-get install ntfs-3g
```

Once done, run this command in terminal:

```
sudo ntfsfix /dev/sda1
```

You may have to convert the volume.  To do that you might want to take a look at [this](http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=2102917).

Comment: done, but it still has the same error and with fdisk-l it still says it is SFS System

Comment: How did you solve it?

Comment: Weird, this did solve a similar problem I've got :)