# Unable to mount external hard disk

Tags: disk

My hard disk suddenly appears to be inaccessible, with the following error:

```
Unable to mount external HD

Error mounting: mount exited with exit code 13: $MFT must be non-resident.
Failed to load $MFT: Input/output error
Failed to mount '/dev/sdc1': Input/output error
NTFS is either inconsistent, or there is a hardware fault, or it's a
SoftRAID/FakeRAID hardware. In the first case run chkdsk /f on Windows
then reboot into Windows twice. The usage of the /f parameter is very
important! If the device is a SoftRAID/FakeRAID then first activate
it and mount a different device under the /dev/mapper/ directory, (e.g.
/dev/mapper/nvidia_eahaabcc1). Please see the 'dmraid' documentation
for more details.
```

The information inside the HD is valuable for me,Any help please?

Answer (score 0):

First, as you said

> The information inside the HD is valuable for me

I would suggest to use [testdisk utility](https://askubuntu.com/a/24951/95393) and attempt to recover your data into a safe place. In future, of course you should make backups of your important data.

[Use smartmontools](https://askubuntu.com/a/317246/95393) and check the disk's health. If it's ok, you should follow the "error's suggestion" and run the `chkdsk` command from a Windows PC.

If you don't have Windows available, an alternative method is to use `ntfsfix` command which is included in `ntfs-3g` package. From there you can attempt a repair. See an example [here](https://askubuntu.com/a/288904/95393).

**A way to ensure that your data will be remain intact, does not exist.**